# Is it possible to configure Apache to not listen on port 80 when connecting from localhost

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-hosting, linux-networking, apache-2.4

Is it possible to configure Apache to not listen on port 80 when connecting from localhost, but allow the connection on port 80 from an external IP?

Comment: you can block with iptables access from localhost to port 80 while allowing all other traffic, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Because I need the port 80 on localhost released to another application that also uses port 80, but this application lets not change the door 

Need to somehow free up port 80 to localhost and I need that Apache continues to function externally. 

Sorry my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with multiple [listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directives

```
Listen 192.0.2.1:80
Listen 203.0.113.1:80
```

> Multiple Listen directives may be used to specify a number of addresses and ports to listen to. The server will respond to requests from any of the listed addresses and ports.

---

On a CentOS System I have to hand

> Listen 192.168.254.16:80

```
netstat -tnlp | grep :80
tcp     0   0 192.168.254.16:80       0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      15014/httpd

telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

Connection Refused generally means nothing is listening which can be seen from the netstat output.

> Listen 80

```
netstat -tnlp | grep :80
tcp        0      0 :::80            :::*      LISTEN      15135/httpd

telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: I did it, but he keeps coming up on localhost

Comment: @user2577532: This works as expected on a CentOS system I have to hand.

Comment: Thanks Iain, worked perfectly! I was doing the wrong file apache2.conf the correct file is ports.conf Thank you very much!